# WPF custom elements style

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to have couple of customized buttons in my app, with icons and simple styles for click and hover (one template for all buttons but different icons, color etc). Icons should change color on hover and click.  Which approach is most efficient?

I thought about some custom control or separated style for each button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define an attached property for the icon and declare a button template that will respect that attached property. That's quite simple:

**Attached property:**

```
internal static class IconProperties
{
    #region Data
    private const string IconPropertyName = "Icon";
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(IconPropertyName,
                                            typeof(Geometry),
                                            typeof(IconProperties),
                                            new(default(Geometry)));

    public static void SetIcon(DependencyObject o, Geometry value)
        => o.SetValue(IconProperty, value);

    public static Geometry GetIcon(DependencyObject o)
        => (Geometry)o.GetValue(DataProperty);
    #endregion

    #region Height
    private const string HeightPropertyName = "Height";
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(HeightPropertyName,
                                            typeof(double),
                                            typeof(IconProperties),
                                            new(default(double)));

    public static void SetHeight(DependencyObject o, double value)
        => o.SetValue(HeightProperty, value);

    public static double GetHeight(DependencyObject o)
        => (double)o.GetValue(HeightProperty);
    #endregion

    #region Width
    private const string WidthPropertyName = "Width";
    public static readonly DependencyProperty WidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(WidthPropertyName,
                                            typeof(double),
                                            typeof(IconProperties),
                                            new(default(double)));

    public static void SetWidth(DependencyObject o, double value)
        => o.SetValue(WidthProperty, value);

    public static double GetWidth(DependencyObject o)
        => (double)o.GetValue(WidthProperty);
    #endregion

    #region Margin
    private const string MarginPropertyName = "Margin";
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MarginProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(MarginPropertyName,
                                            typeof(Thickness),
                                            typeof(IconProperties),
                                            new(default(Thickness)));

    public static void SetMargin(DependencyObject o, Thickness value)
        => o.SetValue(MarginProperty, value);

    public static Thickness GetMargin(DependencyObject o)
        => (Thickness)o.GetValue(MarginProperty);
    #endregion
}
```

**Button template:**

```
<Border x:Name="Root"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
        <Viewbox Height="{Binding Path=(ap:IconProperties.Height), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                 Margin="{Binding Path=(ap:IconProperties.Margin), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                 Stretch="Uniform"
                 Width="{Binding Path=(ap:IconProperties.Width), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}">
            <Path x:Name="Icon"
                  Data="{Binding Path=(ap:IconProperties.Icon), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                  Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
        </Viewbox>

        <TextBlock x:Name="TextContent"
                   Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                   Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Lots of details are omitted here since they are not so important. To animate your button you can use `VisualStateManager` and also you can define more properties for your icon, like opacity, snapping to pixels, etc.

After you have both the attached property and template the usage would be pretty basic:

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource MyAwesomeTempalte}"
        nsWithAttachedProperties:IconProperties.Icon="{StaticResource MyAwesomeIcon}"/>
```